# Problema al ejecutar un click funtion

Tags: jquery

ok chicos tengo el siguiente problema tengo un boton que al clickearlo muestra un div con cierta informacion y al clikearlo por segunda ves oculta ese div,  todo bien pero lo que yo necesito es que el div se oculte al yo dar click en cualquier lado de la pagina mas o menos como en esta misma pagina que das click en las notificaciones y se muestran las notificaciones y que si das click en cualquier lado de la pagina inmediatamente se oculta entienden a lo que me refiero?

he intentado hacer eso con el siguiente codigo pero me genera ciertos errores aqui se los dejo

```js
$("#show").toggle(function(){

$("#show-info").fadeIn("fast")


},function(){

$("html").click(function(){ $("#show-info").fadeOut("fast")}) })
```

```css
#container{
  background:yellow;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  bottom:0;
}

#show-info{
  
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.4.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="show-info"></div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="show">
  
     Notify
  
  </button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

como veran itento hacer algo parecido pero genera algunos problemas, si se dan cuenta al clickear el boton muestra el div oculto pero si lo clikeas otra ves no lo esconde pero si clikeas en cualkier lado si lo esconde y entonce cuando lo esconde para mostrarlo tienes que clikear el boton dos veces alguna idea de como puedo hacer lo que quiero sin errores gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo teniendo click handlers separados para el boton y el html.  Ademas necesitas `event.stopPropagation()` que evita que el evento click se propage a los contenedores padres del boton.  Te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
$("#show").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#show-info").fadeToggle("fast");

});

$("html").click(function(){ 
  $("#show-info").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```css
#container{
  background:yellow;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  bottom:0;
}

#show-info{
  
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.4.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="show-info"></div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="show">
  
     Notify
  
  </button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ey genial no savia acerca de   `event.stopPropagation()` gracias inverstigare acerca ello funciono perfecto